# Implement ToOwned for user-defined types

Tags: rust, ownership

Consider the following example code:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct DataRef<'a> {
    text: &'a str,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct DataOwned {
    text: String,
}
```

I am going to implement `ToOwned` for `DataRef` in this way:

```rust
impl ToOwned for DataRef<'_> {
    type Owned = DataOwned;

    fn to_owned(&self) -> DataOwned {
        DataOwned {
            text: self.text.to_owned(),
        }
    }
}
```

Literally, it makes sense right? But there are some problems.

---

The first problem is, since `ToOwned` provides a [blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html#implementors):

```rust
impl<T> ToOwned for T where T: Clone { ... }
```

the above code will give a compile error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::borrow::ToOwned` for type `DataRef<'_>`
  --> src/main.rs:13:1
   |
13 | impl ToOwned for DataRef<'_> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `alloc`:
           - impl<T> ToOwned for T
             where T: Clone;
```

Well, we can make some compromises. Let's remove `#[derive(Clone)]` from `DataRef`. (However, I can't do that in my real case, because it's a breaking change and doesn't make sense)

---

And then the second problem, the associated type `Owned` of `ToOwned` [requires](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html) that it implements [`Borrow<Self>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html).

```rust
pub trait ToOwned {
    type Owned: Borrow<Self>;

    fn to_owned(&self) -> Self::Owned;

    ...
}
```

If we implement `Borrow` for `DataOwned` as it is defined:

```rust
impl<'a> Borrow<DataRef<'a>> for DataOwned {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &DataRef<'a> {
        DataRef { text: &self.text }
    }
}
```

this is obviously impossible, because we cannot store a `DataRef` somewhere.

---

So my questions are:

- Is there any way to implement `ToOwned` for the above example?
- Consider the problems above, is `ToOwned` not supposed to be implemented manually by users? Because I can't imagine a real example to oppose this point.
- (Optional Answer) If changes to the definition of std `ToOwned` are allowed, are there any possible improvements to make it better? (Unstable and unimplemented Rust features are allowed)

Comment: `borrow::ToOwned` is closely tied to `borrow:Cow<T>`, which requires `T: ToOwned`. There are `impl` of `PartialEq`, `Ord` and such for `Cow`, which is where the `Borrow` requirement comes from: Because `Borrow` guarantees that the owned and the borrowed variant behave the same, `Cow` can compare and order to itself, irrespective of whether the values are of the borrowed or owned variant. `Cow` works because `ToOwned` and `Borrow` make it possible to go seamlessly from one to the other. Can you give some details on *why* you want to implement `ToOwned`?

Comment: @user2722968 Thanks for pointing out that it is related to Cow. I just want my types to be robust and user-friendly, and to_owned is another option besides into. I literally think it makes sense to implement ToOwned, which is somewhat similar to implementing it for str and Path (although I know these are unsized).

Comment: Is your last question "assuming I can change std", or "if I want to write my own trait"?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman It's "assuming you can change std".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problems you are seeing are because `ToOwned` isn't supposed to be implemented *for a reference type* but for a *referent.* Notice what [the standard library implementations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html#implementors) look like:

```rust
impl ToOwned for str
impl ToOwned for CStr
impl ToOwned for OsStr
impl ToOwned for Path
impl<T> ToOwned for [T]
```

These are all `!Sized, !Clone` types which always appear inside of some generic pointer type (e.g. `&str`, `Box<str>`, `&Path`) or specialized owning pointer type (`String` contains a `str`; `PathBuf` contains a `Path`; `Vec<T>` contains a `[T]`). The purpose of `ToOwned` is to allow conversion from a *reference* to the data — not something you called `FooRef` but an actual `&` — to the specialized owning pointer type, in such a way that the transformation is *reversible and consistent* (that's what the `Borrow<Self>` is about).

If you wanted to get the benefits of `Borrow` and `ToOwned`, you'd need to define a type which isn't a reference but something a reference can point to, like this:

```rust
use std::borrow::Borrow;
#[repr(transparent)]
struct Data {
    text: str,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct DataOwned {
    text: String,
}

impl Borrow<Data> for DataOwned {
    fn borrow<'s>(&'s self) -> &'s Data {
        // Use unsafe code to change type of referent.
        // Safety: `Data` is a `repr(transparent)` wrapper around `str`.
        let ptr = &*self.text as *const str as *const Data;
        unsafe { &*ptr }
    }
}

impl ToOwned for Data {
    type Owned = DataOwned;
    fn to_owned(&self) -> DataOwned {
        DataOwned { text: String::from(&self.text) }
    }
}
```

However, note that this strategy *only* works for a single contiguous block of data (such as the UTF-8 bytes in a `str`). There is no way to implement `Borrow` + `ToOwned` in a way that would work for a `DataOwned` that contains *two* strings. (It could be done for one string and some fixed-sized data, but that would still be challenging because custom dynamically-sized types aren't very well-supported by Rust as yet.)

It isn't often worth doing all this for a `String` wrapper, but it might be worthwhile if you want to enforce some stronger type/validity invariant about the contents (e.g. "all characters are ASCII" or "the string (or string slice) is a well-formed JSON fragment"), *and* you want to be able to interact with existing generic code that expects `ToOwned` to be implemented.

If you just want to be able to call a `.to_owned()` method on a `DataRef`, don't bother with the `ToOwned` trait; just write an inherent (non-trait) method.

Comment: The `String` wrapper is just an example, in my real case this structure contains more fields. I will consider your last suggestion. +1 for the detailed explanation.

Comment: I'd like to create str wrapper with some validation. Going wih your suggestion I'd write `#[repr(transparent)] struct ValidStr(str);`. But then. how could I create an instance of such type? In particular, I have no idea how to implement `TryFrom<&str> for &ValidStr` or something similar, is it even possible?

Comment: @Dekakaruk In your `TryFrom` implementation, you'd do the same thing as the `Borrow` implementation in my code does, except with a validation first.